# Scala - creating multiple files

Tags: scala

I am trying to create multiple files. For example, `t1.txt`, `t2.txt`, etc.
I was thinking of something like code below, but it doesn't work:

```
 val nbFiles = 15
 for(n <- 1 to nbFiles) {
     val writer = new PrintWriter(new File("t$n.txt"))
     writer.write("Hello Scala")
     writer.close()
 }
```

I need a `for` loop for making some process on each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [interpolate the string](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) by preceding it with an `s`:

```
val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(s"t$n.txt"))
                                      ^
```